# NoHostAvailable for Cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra

I'm trying to insert Python dictionary into Cassandra. 
But I got `NoHostAvailable` error when I was trying to connect to the DB.
Could someone help me figuring out?

Code:

```
# cassandra server started in Terminal on Mac
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster()
session = cluster.connect()
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoHostAvailable                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-dc85f20fd4f5> in <module>()
----> 1 session = cluster.connect()

/Users/a/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.so in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect (cassandra/cluster.c:11030)()

/Users/a/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.so in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect (cassandra/cluster.c:10872)()

/Users/a/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.so in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect (cassandra/cluster.c:10760)()

/Users/a/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.so in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection.connect (cassandra/cluster.c:35173)()

/Users/a/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.so in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._reconnect_internal (cassandra/cluster.c:36007)()

NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(61, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

Warning:

```
WARNING:cassandra.cluster:[control connection] Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2067, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._reconnect_internal (cassandra/cluster.c:35763)
    return self._try_connect(host)
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2087, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._try_connect (cassandra/cluster.c:36224)
    connection = self._cluster.connection_factory(host.address, is_control_connection=True)
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 789, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connection_factory (cassandra/cluster.c:8980)
    return self.connection_class.factory(address, self.connect_timeout, *args, **kwargs)
  File "cassandra/connection.py", line 306, in cassandra.connection.Connection.factory (cassandra/connection.c:5051)
    conn = cls(host, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/a/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/io/libevreactor.py", line 264, in __init__
    self._connect_socket()
  File "cassandra/connection.py", line 340, in cassandra.connection.Connection._connect_socket (cassandra/connection.c:6123)
    raise socket.error(sockerr.errno, "Tried connecting to %s. Last error: %s" % ([a[4] for a in addresses], sockerr.strerror or sockerr))
error: [Errno 61] Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused
ERROR:cassandra.cluster:Control connection failed to connect, shutting down Cluster:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 844, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect (cassandra/cluster.c:10760)
    self.control_connection.connect()
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2041, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection.connect (cassandra/cluster.c:35173)
    self._set_new_connection(self._reconnect_internal())
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2076, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._reconnect_internal (cassandra/cluster.c:36007)
    raise NoHostAvailable("Unable to connect to any servers", errors)
NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(61, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

Comment: The most obvious answer is that your local system isn't running cassandra, or it isn't listening on 127.0.0.1:9042.

Is cassandra running? Is it listening on 9042? Can you connect with telnet?

Answer (score 0):

Before connecting to your cluster you have to provide the nodes contact point and auth provider or you have to run cassandra on your localhost ip address.

try this :

```
ap = PlainTextAuthProvider(username=<username>,password=<password>)
cass_contact_points=[<ip address of your node>,..]
cluster = Cluster(cass_contact_points,auth_provider=ap)
session = cluster.connect(<keyspace name>)
```

Comment: I'm getting 
Last error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Answer (score 0):

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])
session = cluster.connect('keyspace')
```

- Ensure cassandra running correctly
- Cluster = Cluster () or cluster = Cluster (['ip_server_db'])
- A reference that helps https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html
- A reference that helps https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/auth.html